# Clean up docker image used as a Jenkins agent?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm using the following declarative pipeline in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build Image'){
            steps {
                sh "docker build -t my_tag ${WORKSPACE} --pull"
            }
        }
        stage('Run Stuff In Docker'){
            agent {
                docker {
                    image "my_tag"
                    args '--rm -v /some_location:/some_location:rw'
                }
            }
            stages{
                // do stuff inside the container
            }
        }
        stage('Push Image'){
            steps {  
                sh "docker push my_tag"
            } 
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            sh "docker rmi my_tag"
            successNotify()
        }
        failure {
            failureNotify()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a docker agent, running some tests inside the container, pushing the image to a repository, and then I'd like to clean up the image after all is said and done. However, I keep getting the following error:

> Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository
> reference "my_tag" (must force) - container a4ed94a24dca is using its
> referenced image 181b303be4fe

I see that Jenkins is running the agent with `-d` so my guess is that even though I have included `--rm`, the container isn't being removed before the `post {success}` block runs. Is there a nice way to clean up the agent image automatically here?

Comment: You could execute the tests inside of the container run from the image via the Docker pipeline plugin instead as that terminates once the steps are completed. This is an alternative usage that achieves your goal instead of a fix to the image cleanup. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `docker` global var and its `inside()` function which start container and stop container once `inside()` function done.

More detail from [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/pipelines/docker-workflow)

```
stage('Run Stuff In Docker'){
    steps {
        script {
            docker.image("my_tag").inside("-v /some_location:/some_location:rw") {
                // do stuff inside the container
                sh '''

                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```